# Search Multiple Values associated with Single XML Element(Key) using MarkLogic Java API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I have Multiple Documents Stored in Marklogic as Mentioned

```
<testData>
<datatype>
    <datatypename>datatypename1</datatypename>
    <datatype>datatype1</datatype>
</datatype>
<datavalue>
    <code>code1</code>
    <value>value1</value>
</datavalue>
<datavalue>
    <code>code2</code>
    <value>value2</value>
</datavalue>
<datavalue>
    <code>code3</code>
    <value>value3</value>
</datavalue>
</testData>
```

**Requirement : I want to search all the documents which is having same key but different values using Maklogic Java API**

Example : in above XML `<code>` element having multiple values like `code1`, `code2`

I tried Below code

```
        QueryManager manager = client.newQueryManager();
        StructuredQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
        StructuredQueryDefinition queryDefinition1 = queryBuilder.value(queryBuilder.element("code"), "code1");
        StructuredQueryDefinition queryDefinition2 = queryBuilder.value(queryBuilder.element("code"), "code2");

        StructuredQueryDefinition definition = queryBuilder.and(queryDefinition1, queryDefinition2);

        SearchHandle searchHandle = new SearchHandle();
        manager.search(definition, searchHandle);
```

here i am using multiple `StructuredQueryDefinition` for each element value like `queryDefinition1` for `code1` , `queryDefinition2` for `code2` instead of doing this i want to do like and it should return a document which is having `code` as element name and `code1` and `code2` as its values,

```
StructuredQueryDefinition queryDefinition1 = queryBuilder.value(queryBuilder.element("code"), "code1 AND code2");
```

Please tell me whether it is possible or not using Marklogic Java API and Without Creating Element Range Index for `code` element.

Comment: I guess you could achieve this with an XPath query: /testdata/[count(distinct-values(./datavalue/code/text()) > 1] .

Comment: In general, it's better to express the structure of a query outside of strings where possible. In what way is the first example with queryBuilder.and() failing to do what you want?

Comment: If You look at the above search code...Here i am using queryDefinition1 for specifying element value code1 and again queryDefinition2 for value code2 and then I am doing queryBuilder.and(queryDefinition1, queryDefinition2) so instead of performing AND operation like this....i wanted to do like queryBuilder.value(queryBuilder.element("code"), "code1 AND code2")